Error during the Migration from Payara 5 to Payara6 version (6.2024.4)
I’ve upgraded a java application, with Payara Micro and maven, from the Payara server from version 5 (5.52.0 version) to 6 version (6.2024.4).
The build is ok but I get this at the runtime:
[WARNING]  [Annotation-Framework] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1715772499197] [levelValue: 900]
Failed to handle annotation [ @jakarta.resource.spi.ConfigProperty(ignore=false, description={},
 type=java.lang.String.class, defaultValue=“”, supportsDynamicUpdates=false, confidential=false) ] 
on class [ com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl ], reason : not a rar bundle context

…

[SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main]
 [timeMillis: 1715786136811] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001301: 
Annotation QualifierInstance {annotationClass=interface org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoints, values=value=[Lorg.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoint;@e283976}} is not a qualifier – WELD-001301: 
Annotation QualifierInstance {annotationClass=interface org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoints, values=value=[Lorg.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoint;@e283976}} is not a qualifier

I cannot find any references on the internet. Anyone met this already? Thank you!

The solution:
I mistakenly put the <scope>provided</scope> directive under the modules libraries, instead of the root one.
It is working after the correction.
